# How can I use a custom domain for public and private DNS when provisioning instances on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a VPC where provisioning of EC2 instances is going to be automated, but each instance is going to be assigned a public dns of "`ec2-{public-ip}.{region}.compute.amazonaws.com`" and a private dns of "`ip-{private-ip}.me-south-1.compute.internal`". What I want here is to be able to use my own domain (using Route53) to make instances get a public dns of something like

> "instance-id.customdomain.com"

And to keep updating the dns entries on Route53 after each reboot of the EC2 instance.

Is there anyway to accomplish this from within the VPC settings or Route53's? If not, how could such a thing be accomplished?

Comment: Normally you would use EIP to get static public IP for the instsances.

Comment: @Marcin It's a legitimate solution but has limitations as the number of Elastic IPs that can be used is limited and the EC2 instances I have is quite large.

Comment: For dynamic solutions, you could consider detecting state changes of the instances (into running state event) using CloudWatch Event rules which would trigger a lambda. The lambda would in turn update route 53. Ideal solution would be R53 autodiscovery, but I think its only for ECS, not for EC2.

Comment: Are the instances in ASG? If yes, you clould also use lifescycles hooks to do the R53 updates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no AWS offered solution to it. You have to create your own scripts to achieve this.

> instance-id.customdomain.com -> instance public ip

You can attach an instance profile and add [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) to EC2 at launch. It's easily achievable by using some AWS CLI commands. For example, use [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) to get the public ip of a particular instance identified by the instance id. Then use [change-resource-record-sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html) to add an A record in route53.

> keep updating the dns entries on Route53 after each reboot of the EC2 instance

You can either treat this as part of the EC2 reboot job or check and sync ip with route53 on every OS reboot.

Alternative: Use EIP so you don't need to monitor the public IP change.